# gets_s Error C2660 "function does not take 1 argument" - Very Confused

Tags: c, visual-studio

So I have looked into this problem as thoroughly as I could however I have been unable to identify a solution (Very new to programming).

Basically I am trying to read in a .txt file, however as soon as I ask the user to input the name of the file with the get_s function, I get error C2660 - "error C2660: 'gets_s': function does not take 1 arguments".

Here is an example of my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{
FILE *fileread1;
char file1[10];
char read_char1;
char ch;
{

    printf("Enter a filename : ");
    gets_s("file1.txt");

    fileread1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
```

Thanks to everyone that has a look, I appreciate the problem is likely something glaringly obvious, however I am quite new to programming. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gets_s` takes two arguments, not one. Here is a reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets.

**You should not be using this function.** Rather, you should be using `fgets`. It is my understanding that `gets` and `gets_s` both do not protect against buffer overflow.

To use fgets as you would use `gets`, simply pass `stdin` as the input file pointer. Here is a usage example:

```
char buffer[100];
fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
```

Here is a good resource for `fgets` that goes into more detail: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fgets&sektion=3

## Correction

After some research, `gets_s` appears to be a version of `gets` that protects against buffer overflow, however I couldn't find it in `stdio.h` on my OSX machine nor on my FreeBSD server. It doesn't appear to be standard, so I would advise using `fgets`.